# WAMP Server Giving me 403 Forbidden Error When testing files

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I installed WAMP Server 3.0.1 on my Windows 10, i can access the phpmyadmin page and edit databases and all that.

But when i try to test an html file linked to a php file from localhost
(EX: http://localhost///C:/Users/username/Desktop/Testing/detail.html)

it gives me the 403 Forbidden Error

Thank you for your assisstance, i searched the web and did not find clear anserws

Answer (score 1):

Please can you clarify what do you mean by:

> html file linked to a php file

Since you haven't given so many details about your issue. I will try to answer your question in parts as there might be different possibilities

1. `http://localhost///C:/Users/username/Desktop/Testing/detail.html`

   The URL that you try doesn't seem to be correct URL. It seems you're doing something wrong. When you install web server to your local machine you will not need any URLs in such format

   ```
   C:/Users/username/Desktop/Testing/detail.html
   ```

   Maybe you can try to copy your files in `www` folder and then run it like:

   ```
   http://localhost/detail.html
   ```
2. If you are passing an HTML file to your PHP Code I should say there is no PHP file written in your URL. Also passing URL which is from outside web server environment is totally wrong idea which can cause security issues sooner or later. You should consider changing your design idea. Maybe try to look up examples those are availeble in the internet.

Also here is another suggestion to you: Ask the question itself to yourself before posting here.

In conclusion my suggestions are; please edit your question to provide as much detail as you can with a clarified version of your problem. So helpful people on this website will able and happy to help you.